# Report - uses of deprecated fields, methods and classes even if suppressed with @SuppressWarnings

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, deprecated

In order to maintain clean and healthy reports and also to get quickly alerted if new things pop up, we have annotated some fields/methods/classes with @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

So far so good.

So now we want to upgrade a dependency, let's say hibernate 5.2 to 5.3.

To assess risks of the upgrade, we want to check if we are using deprecated methods.

(Note: e..g https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/SQLQuery.html is deprecated in 5.2 and no longer works with positional parameters in 5.3).

Anybody aware of a tool that gives me a breakdown of deprecated usages?

Apart form deleting all @SuppressWarnings at least temporarily (which might be a good thing btw) and then running javac with "-deprecation" option I haven't got any ideas.

I've checked (spot|find)bugs, but neither seems to care about deprecated methods; sonarqube has only rules that apply to the whole codebase/quality profile, and neither intellij nor eclipse seem to care about a filter by dependency either.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question after some thoughts, it seems that getting deprecated methods from the dependencies javadoc and then grepping through .java files will do the trick for us since we don't do wildcard imports